# Change file manager used by Firefox on Lubuntu

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, firefox, filemanager

I'm running Firefox 28 on Lubuntu 14.04 and I've noticed that when using "Open Containing Folder" it opens the folder in "Files" file manager instead of PCManFM. This is slightly annoying, so I've searched `Tools > Options` and `about:config`, but couldn't find anything related to the choice of the file manager.

I tried switching default manager to something else and switching it back, but it didn't work. Editing `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`, `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`, `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` and `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` also had no effect.

So, is there any reasonable way to change the file manager used by Firefox?

Btw. I'm aware of [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/q/267514/) but this shouldn't be considered a duplicate, because it is for Lubuntu and general, not specific file manager (although I intend to use the answer specifically for PCManFM).

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by [Mozilla Firefox Bug 727422, comment 30](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=727422#c30), I found out that Firefox is currently (FF 36.0, Ubuntu 14.10 with LXDE) using the *org.freedesktop.FileManager1-Interface* on the Dbus session bus. As stated in the specification of this interface, Nautilus (also known as Files) is the only file manager that implements this interface. Therefore, Firefox will always choose Nautilus as file manager if it is installed.

So there are two possibilities to resolve this *first* problem:

1. Uninstall Nautilus/Files
2. Tamper with the *org.freedesktop.FileManager1-Interface* that Nautilus offers to disable this method of Firefox to open a file manager. Therefore, you could just delete `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.FileManager1.service`. But maybe, it is a better approach to use the proposed solution of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/133133/comments/74 and create `~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.FileManager1.service` and set its exec-line to `/usr/bin/false` (just copy `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.FileManager1.service` there and change it). This avoids deleting/editing a file created by your package manager and you do not need super user privileges. After having done so, you possibly need a restart.

As soon as Firefox can not use the Dbus-Interface anymore, it will fall back to a second way to figure out which file manager to start. This will lead to the *second* problem:

The default applications should be configured with several different `mimeapps.list`-files with different priorities. It **seems to me** that Firefox is correctly consulting the files `~/.config/mimeapps.list`, `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and `/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list` but not the *deprecated* `defaults.list`-file. So, you have to add the `inode/directory=pcmanfm.desktop`-entry to one of the three files mentioned above. This can also be done by calling `gvfs-mime --set inode/directory pcmanfm.desktop` or `xdg-mime default pcmanfm.desktop inode/directory`.

Lxde itself seems to use `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` to determine its default file manager. Therefore, you have to edit one of those files manually.

Comment: Very informative and detailed, on bunsenlabs it works with your suggestion of the xdg-mime command.