# "Open containing folder" in Firefox opens Thunar instead of default Nautilus

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, nautilus, xfce, thunar

After going through several already-answered questions on AskUbuntu and Unix's stackexchange, Firefox's "Open containing folder" option (when a file is downloaded) still opens folder in Thunar File Manager, even though my default file manager is Nautilus. (However, it's Nautilus that's opened when prompted to save a file, for example, meaning, I guess, that Firefox is somehow aware that Nautilus exists.) I'm on XFCE (Ubuntu 22) so I can't uninstall Thunar without causing core problems (already tried that).

Nautilus (under the name Files) is set a default File Manager. In the GUI of my "Applications by default" app, inode/directory and inode/mount-point are set to Files.

I've tried to modify every `mimeapps.list` and `defaults.list` and `mimeinfo.cache` files possible, every single one of them has the following line:

```
inode/directory=org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
```

(Some of them have also `[Default Applications]` on the line before)

Except one `mimeinfo.cache` that has "Catfish" and "Thunar" *after* Nautilus. But removing mention of Thunar with sudo doesn't change anything.

I also updated `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.FileManager1.service` according to suggestions, that didn't change anything.

I've closed/reopened my user session, also restarted my computer, nothing changed.

What have I missed?

Please don't mark as duplicate, since none of the answers provided in below questions solutioned my problem:

- [Change file manager used by Firefox on Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530779/change-file-manager-used-by-firefox-on-lubuntu/590123#590123)
- ["Open containing folder" in Firefox does not use my default file manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267514/open-containing-folder-in-firefox-does-not-use-my-default-file-manager)
- [How to force Firefox to open downloads with new default file manager (Nemo)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565479/how-to-force-firefox-to-open-downloads-with-new-default-file-manager-nemo)
- [Make nemo the default file browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260244/make-nemo-the-default-file-browser/260249#260249)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336982/how-to-avoid-a-program-taking-over-the-file-manager-when-opening-a-folder-in-tha/336984#336984
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333254/set-standard-file-browser-for-open-containing-folder
- [Stop folders opening with different application than the file manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73979/stop-folders-opening-with-different-application-than-the-file-manager/404332#404332)

Comment: Did you check firefox settings? Check `Setting`>`General`>`applications` within firefox.

Comment: @vanadium `xdg-open ~` does launch Nautilus!

Comment: @mook765 I did... I don't think any "content type" calls Thunar: all "content types" has either "Save file", "Open in Firefox" or "Always ask" related actions, except for "magnet" and "appstream" content types that have "Use system handler (default)" related action. But I don't think it has anything to do with "Open containing folder" option, has it? When Firefox ask where I wan't to save a file, it launches correctly Nautilus. It's only when it opens containing folder of a downloaded file that it launches Thunar.

Comment: Any update? -- Usually I was able to fix similar problem (I'm on Plasma) by modifying the mimeinfo.cache file, but with Thunar something different must be involved. A Thunar-specific question might be needed.

Comment: @mook765 - That has nothing to do with this because that Firefox setting is about file types. This affects the location of all downloaded files. I suspect a more Thunar-specific problem here.

Comment: I have seen a similar problem in the last 10 years very very often and I have been able to solve it by changing something like  `defaults.list` or `mimeinfo.cache`: with this exception in my linked post involving exclusively Thunar, which was fixed by the dbus service method. I am very confident that  your case is similar, even if services might be a bit different per desktop. By the way: *IS* this problem limited to Firefox? (e.g. opening a file location in Audacious playlist opens what file manager?) And what are the contents of your `org.gnome.Nautilus.service` file?

Comment: Are you sure it's opening Thunar or is it just not opening nautilus. This sounds like an XY problem where you're assuming the problem is that it's opening Thunar when it's actually opening a generic file explorer.

Comment: @mchid I don't quite understand you. The fact is that it is Thunar that's opening and not Nautilus, whether it is because it's "willingly" opening Thunar or because it's not opening Nautilus and is opening instead a "generic file explorer" that happens to be Thunar. The problem stays the same: I want Nautilus to be opened, not Thunar. Would you have a solution in case it's what you're hypothesising?

Comment: @Chloé I'm pretty sure it uses GtkFileChooser. The default search function is similar to Thunar in that it's not recursive search. In additon to GtkFileChooser is xdg-desktop-portal and xdg-desktop-portal-gtk which provides a portal for sandboxed apps like Snap apps such as firefox to interact with the filesystem. If you want to search recursively like Nautilus, click on one of the bookmarked directories (on the left side of the window) and then start typing to search. This will invoke a recursive search similar to Nautilus behavior.

Comment: @Chloé But again, I think xdg-desktop-portal-gtk uses GtkFileChooser. There is one thing you can try. Go to `about:config` in firefox and search for `xdg-desktop-portal.file-picker` and change the value from `2` to `1`. Then, restart firefox. At one point, I believe this made a difference for me but then it was back to the old behavior. I use nightly so it might be a recent update that isn't applied to older versions (and the snap version may handle this differently).

Comment: @Chloé And FYI, `xdg-desktop-portal.file-picker` is not the full key name, but that search should bring up the one you need.

Comment: @mchid thanks for all these explanations. Sadly, the value of this key is currently 1. I guess I changed it at some point during my hours of research on the matter...

Answer (score 1):

Imagining this is related to [my case](https://askubuntu.com/a/1430542/925128):

Look at `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/` and find:

```
 org.xfce.FileManager.service
 org.xfce.Thunar.FileManager1.service
```

Because I was using Dolphin on Kubuntu I had also `org.kde.dolphin.FileManager1.service`. I have copied the line `SystemdService=plasma-dolphin.service` from the "dolphin" file into the other two, replacing the corresponding "thunar" lines there.

In your case you should use the variables corresponding to your case, involving "nautilus".

They might look like so:

`org.xfce.FileManager.service`:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.xfce.FileManager
Exec=/usr/bin/Thunar --gapplication-service
SystemdService=nautilus.service
```

`org.xfce.Thunar.FileManager1.service`:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.FileManager1
Exec=/usr/bin/Thunar --gapplication-service
SystemdService=nautilus.service
```

I am not sure about `org.gnome.Nautilus.service`: but maybe something like:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.FileManager1
Exec=/usr/bin/nautilus --daemon
SystemdService=nautilus.service
```

---

Other solutions from my sources (see link), which I haven't tested but are confirmed to work:

- running `killall Thunar` at login
- running `systemctl --user mask thunar`

I think these solutions cannot be used on a desktop like Xfce (where Thunar is handling the desktop) without further settings that would fully replace Thunar's functions.

Comment: My problem is that I don't have such "SystemdService" line in my `org.gnome.Nautilus.service` file... I tried `systemcl status <service>` with `nautilus.service`, `org.gnome.Nautilus.service` and `gnome.nautilus.service` (in place of `<service>`) but none was a valid service. Is Nautilus even a service ? 

I confirm that I cannot kill Thunar, otherwise my desktop icons don't work anymore (among other things). Also tried solution proposed [there](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1285711#c39) without success...

Comment: @Chloé - for your needs related to uninstaling or killing Thunar, [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/543468/341192) might be helpful. - Considering  `I don't have such "SystemdService" line`: what happens if you create the files that you don't have? I will post detail contents in my answer. I see [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man7/systemd.special.7.html) that `nautilus.service` should exist.

Comment: As a workaround: I think Thunar is rather limited comparatively, but not compared to Nautilus. On the GTK side I find Nemo the most complete file manager (and the one that vaguely stands comparison to Dolphin). I have posted in the previous comment a link to a post I wrote when using Nemo to replace Thunar in Xfce. I am not sure if the solution is similar for Nautilus but Nemo is similar to Nautilus - maybe.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However Nautilus [doesn't have the desktop icons capacity anymore](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/files-nautilus-v3-28-will-lose-the-desktop-icons-capability/3115/7) so I depend on Thunar to deal with this... / I've added `SystemdService=nautilus.service` on each file mentioned in your answer, and that didn't change a thing. Kinda hopeless about this, especially after reading the [bugzilla] page(https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1285711) you mentioned in another answer.

Comment: I think Nemo (which is a Nautilus fork) has the desktop icons capacity... so I don't think the solution could apply to Nautilus. I thought about changing for Nemo and installed it, but I don't like how it looks (so I removed it straight after). I think I'll have to leave with this Firefox-open-in-folder downside (: