# Firefox opens Thunar no matter what (with "show in folder" downloads option)

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, 22.04, filemanager, thunar

[image]

My problem is similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1425654/925128), but not to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/336982/341192), nor to others linked in these two, which address the general problem of making Firefox to use the default file manager by a necessary setting that specifies that program.

That is to say that no solution expected to work is in fact working here: this doesn't seem to be a general problem of the type "avoid a program taking over the file manager when opening a folder in that program from context menu" or "'Show in folder' in Firefox downloads does not use my default file manager", but a more Thunar-specific problem of the form *"Thunar doesn't respect the settings specifying the default file manager for Firefox"*.

As said in the first linked question,

> "I've tried to modify every `mimeapps.list` and `defaults.list` and
> `mimeinfo.cache` files possible, every single one of them has the
> following line etc"

In my case that line is `inode/directory=org.kde.dolphin.desktop;` , and I have added that even to `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.

Dolphin is my default in all my settings.

I have even installed the `xfce4-settings` and then used `xfce4-mime-settings` to select Dolphin as file manager (uselessly [it seems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528460/341192), as this does not relate to any Xfce or Thunar-specific files) - and I have also selected it in `~/.config/xfce4/helpers.rc` and `/etc/xdg/xfce4/helpers.rc`.

I am in Kubuntu 22.04, I have installed Thunar because I need it's bulk renamer associated with a Dolphin context/service menu, I have fixed this problem many times and I was not expecting it to appear here.

That's why I think is a different problem, based on some setting specific to Thunar or to Firefox - or somehow to them together.

**No other application but Firefox seems affected (unlike in the case of the second linked post) and the same Firefox problem with any other application - excepting Thunar - was fixed in the past by modifying the aforementioned files.**

Replacing `thunar` with `dolphin` in its `/usr/share/applications/thunar.desktop` launcher didn't help.

### UPDATES:

As said [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1285711#c4), and [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/firefox-using-thunar-insted-of-default-file-manager-xfce/55926/5) after sending `kill` signal to Thunar the problem disappears until the Firefox browser is restarted.

Removing the very file `/usr/share/applications/thunar.desktop` is useless.

Adding that file to `~/.local/share/applications` and removing the MimeType line doesn't help.

***Completely removing all "thunar" files from `usr/bin` (because I've noticed that `thunar` and `thunar -B` can be run from other location) Firefox stops opening Thunar of course but opens the default file manager Dolphin only after 10-15 seconds!***

---

Comment: You could try this: copy Thunars `.desktop`-file to `~/.local/share/applications/`, edit this file and remove the line `MimeType=inode/directory;`. This will remove Thunar from all open-with-lists, but since you want to use Thunar only ocasionally, this should be ok. Try if it helps.

Comment: @mook765 - It doesn't work. I don't need Thunar as file manager at all, just the renamer (`thunar -B`). Altering the very file `/usr/share/applications/thunar.desktop` so that `Exec=dolphin` is useless. But oddly killing Thunar avoids the problem until Firefox is restarted.

Comment: @mook765 - Incredibly, completely removing all "thunar" files from usr/bin (because I've noticed that thunar and thunar -B can be run from other location) Firefox stops opening Thunar of course but opens the default file manager Dolphin only after 10-15 seconds!

Comment: @mook765 - digging deeper I've found a solution and posted an answer.Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/firefox-using-thunar-insted-of-default-file-manager-xfce/55926/14) post - linking to [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1285711#c21):

Looking at `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/` we find:

```
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.dolphin.FileManager1.service
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.FileManager.service
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.Thunar.FileManager1.service
```

I have copied the line `SystemdService=plasma-dolphin.service` from the "dolphin" file into the other two, replacing the corresponding "thunar" lines there.

(After this, given in my case the `thunar` binary had been removed already from `usr/bin` and Firefox was opening Dolphin but after a long time: Firefox started opening Dolphin after a normal delay.)

It seems this can be temporary if Thunar is updated, so I've locked it at current version.

Other solutions from link, which I haven't tested but are confirmed to work (but which I guess shouldn't be used on a desktop like Xfce - where Thunar is handling the desktop - without supplementary  settings):

- running `killall Thunar` at login
- running `systemctl --user mask thunar`