# How to change the default file manager used by firefox? Gnome

Tags: gnome, filemanager

I changed the file manager to Thunar by default `xdg-mime default Thunar.desktop inode/directory`, nevertheless the `Open Containing Folder` button in the Dowload window in Firefox opens the Ubuntu's default file manager. (Nautilus?)

- **How can I set Thunar as god default file manager?**

Comment: You probably will need to include information on the desktop if you expect concise answers.

Comment: Desktop? Sorry I thought I wrote it. It's gnome.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in https://askubuntu.com/q/267514/26246 ? see with newest answers first.

Comment: @pomsky Question is unclear, but I guess the user means the "Display the progress of ongoing downloads" button in firefox. In the dropdown, you can open the containing folder of the downloads, and that opens the system file manager. OP uses Gnome but wants that file manager to be thunar instead of nautilus. Link provided by user.dz may be relevant.

Comment: @vanadium That makes sense.

Comment: @user.dz I don't have those settings in Gnome nor Firefox. I also changed/added inode/directory for Thunar in all the mimeinfo and mimecache files they say. After a reboot and reload, still Nautilus...

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/335911/2355 . Maybe try `thunar.desktop` instead of `Thunar.desktop`?

Comment: It's not using Nautilus. It's a default stripped down file explorer that simply looks like Nautilus.

Comment: It's called GtkFileChooser. Are you trying to get a certain behavior from the file chooser? Many people don't know that you can use typeahead or enter the file path by pressing CTRL+L or by simply typing `.` or `/` which will automatically change to filename input mode (Thunar default mode) instead of recursive search (Nautilus default mode).