# How to remove build-essential manually when it is part of another package?

Tags: apt

We installed a Nagios plugin that brought along build-essential, and I'd like to remove it because I don't want build tools on a production server.

When I simulate the *apt-get remove* command:

```
apt-get remove build-essential --simulate
```

It says it will also remove the Nagios plugin.

How can I remove build-essential while keeping the plugin?

Comment: What is the nature of the Nagios plugin? Does it compile source code regularly? It sounds like the plugin writer added a requirement/dependency. The APT command should have flags for removing packages that have dependencies.

Comment: look at this thread and see if the answers offer any assistance.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/17745/how-to-remove-a-deb-without-removing-its-dependencies

Comment: It would be easier to answer this if you said which nagios plugin you are referring to (and where you got it, if not from Ubuntu's repositories).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "nagios plugin" you installed probably lists build-essential as a dependency.

The most common reason a package would list build-essential as a dependency is if that package compiles some source code as part of its installation procedure.  Depending on build-essential is not common practice for packages provided by Ubuntu itself, which on the rare occasions they do require some compilation during install, would not include all of build-essential.

Assuming it's listed as a "requires" dependency there is no way to remove the dependency but leave the package that depends on it using APT. This is a constraint that is enforced by APT for the entire time the package is installed.

In theory if the build tools were only required when the package was installed but are no longer being used, you could *forcibly remove* the various files belonging to build-essential and things would *probably* continue to work.  But this is *definitely not recommended* as it will leave you with a system that, as far as APT/dpkg are concerned, is broken!

You say that you don't want build tools on a production server.  Is this for security reasons?  Because if so, simply not having particular tools available does not really enforce security.  For one, build tools don't give ordinary users any extra privileges - they're still restricted to the same parts of the filesystem they would be anyway.  They couldn't, for example, install code to run as superuser.  Also, regardless of what's installed system-wide a user could still install and run binary tools (such as compilers) inside his or her own home directories with their user privileges.

Comment: some compliance frameworks are sticklers for removing compilers and build tools from production systems. I agree with you that it is a nominal return on investment, security wise; unfortunately, a lot of "compliance" mechanisms are easier to just comply with, rather than try to mitigate with 'logic' and 'common sense'.

Comment: Yes.  The alternative is to remove the offending nagios plugin, really - if not having build-essential is considered a mandatory requirement.  Not knowing anything about the nagios plugin, maybe it's available from other sources which package it differently?

Comment: No properly packaged source should depend on build-essential as it's in essence a meta-package in Ubuntu. They can have it as a recommend if desiring the deps of build-essential to be installed. I'd look for a better packaged version of that plugin

Comment: Good point.  I'll edit my answer a little.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone.  I was basically wondering if there was some option where apt would let you remove a dependency, and you've answered that.