# Catch 22: python-pillow & python-pil apt-get conflict

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I'd like to upgrade to `python-pillow` but the default install (Ubuntu 14.04.5) has given me `python-pil`.

```
> sudo apt-get install python-pillow
...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-pillow_2.7.0-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/pilfont.py', which is also in package python-pil 2.3.0-1ubuntu3
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
...
```

OK, a conflict. Let me just remove that package cos I don't want it...

```
> sudo apt-get remove -f python-pil
...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-allspeak-rest : Depends: python-pillow (>= 2.7.0)
 python-imaging : Depends: python-pil but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Might as well give what it says a shot...

```
> sudo apt-get -f install
...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pillow
...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-pillow_2.7.0-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/pilfont.py', which is also in package python-pil 2.3.0-1ubuntu3
...
```

Back where I started. Can't remove the old or install the new. What can I do now?

---

UPDATE:

I can force uninstall python-pil with the following (from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/32899/196639)):

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-depends python-pil
```

But now I end up with errors such as:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-allspeak-rest : Depends: python-pillow (>= 2.7.0)
 python-imaging : Depends: python-pil but it is not going to be installed
```

I can't have both installed at the same time and yet dependencies say I need to.

Comment: I edited the title to be a bit more interesting :)

Comment: Well, I finally got everything behaving by allowing file overwriting during the install `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/python-pillow_2.7.0-1_amd64.deb` (see [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/176132/196639)). Not a nice solution since the package manager won't know which package those files came from. But at least I can get on with what I'm doing.

Comment: This` is what is fondly referred to as "dependency hell." It is a domain which we were cast into much more frequently in the past. If there are just a few offending files, you can replace them with symlinks to the actual files so you can switch versions just by changing where the symlinks point to without having the apps step all over each other.

Comment: @jozxyqk, would you write that as an answer then check it as the accepted one.

Comment: @user.dz added, but I hope someone finds a better way.

Answer (score 2):

**This isn't a good solution at all, but it's what worked for me** (copied from the comments):

Well, I finally got everything behaving by allowing file overwriting during the install `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/python-pillow_2.7.0-1_amd64.deb` (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/176132/196639)). Not a nice solution since the package manager won't know which package those files came from. But at least I can get on with what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for correct answer, then it is to raise bug report versus `python-pillow` about this.

```
apport-bug python-pillow
```

Possible solutions:

- Change the name of `/usr/bin/pilfont.py` in `python-pillow`, because it's the fork.
- Change the name of `/usr/bin/pilfont.py` in both `python-pillow` & `python-pil` and both should use `update-alternatives` to create `/usr/bin/pilfont.py` symlink.
- `python-pillow` declare `python-pil` in `Breaks:` field, so they could not get installed together in same system (It like pulling the trigger for a war :D).

BTW, `python-pillow` is removed from Ubuntu 16.04.